# How to access referencing outlet on multiple Collection Views on same controller

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xcode8, nscollectionview

I have two collection views that are on one view controller.  I am switching between them from two buttons based on some logic like if user is logged in.  My first collection view works fine but I cant access my second collection view when I try to reference the outlet.

[Reference outlet connected to first collection view successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLkPZ.png)

[Second collection view trying to connect referencing outlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yET0.png)

Is it not possible to connect two collection views to the same view controller?  How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I would use one collection view and switch the data source / logic within it myself. i seriously doubt two objects can reference a single outlet, that wouldn't make sense as you wouldn't know which you were getting, if both were initialized which one are you dealing with?

Comment: well I had one collection view that is displaying all products.  The second collection view is based off a button called "installed"  if the user is logged in and clicks the button then it will display the products they have previously purchased.  My thoughts were that I needed two collection views.  So you're saying I need to switch the data sources and use the same collection view?

Comment: You CAN have two collection views, but have an outlet for each one. productionsCollectionView and purchasedCollectionView. you could also just add a purchased filter on the all products collection view if you wanted

Answer (score 0):

> Is it not possible to connect two collection views to the same view
>   controller? How can I fix this issue?

You CAN connect two collectionViews to the same viewController, but why would you do that? instead, you can add just one collectionView and based on some logic, you should handle the `dataSource` and `delegate` of this one collectionView. You can display the additional data that appears if user is logged-in in a second section of your collectionView -for example-.